# best practical way to bacup/restore a toooo large db with size of ~2TB

Tags: mysql

The ibdata1 file has increased to ~**2TB** and leave only a few GBs free space left in the same disk. What's worse I forgot to turn on innodb_fiel_per_tabe.
I've read from [SO](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/what-is-the-best-way-to-reduce-the-size-of-ibdata-in-mysql) that the only way to reduce ibdata1 is to backup->delete ibdata1->restore;
Now, since the ibdata1 is tooooo large, what's the good way to do it? and how many time(days??)it will take?
I have two other free disk of 2TB available which can be used for backup.

Answer (score 1):

Create a replication slave with `innodb_file_per_table` on. Wait for it to populate. Then make it into the master server (change IP on either the server or the application).

Comment: If you're exceptionally careful about config, user, ports, sockets, datadirs etc you could even set up a second mysql instance on the same physical server as a slave using one of your space disks.

Comment: thanks @danblack, what's the difference between the mysqldump solution(backup&restore)

Comment: and this, less downtime. If you're not changing tables you're probably going to be able to manage this with < 5 mins of downtime (most of which is changing adding a disk assuming its not already there).

Comment: please note that i have only 1 server but multiple disks, is this master-slave approach still fine?

Comment: ^ see comment #1